# (LibGdx) Screen viewport issue

Tags: android, camera, libgdx, viewport, freeze

This is related to Libgdx.
I m developing a game which works logically correct.

Problem:
When game runs on PC it looks fine (FPS 61)
but when run on android (FPS from 47 to 30 keeps falling) (Note 5) its very slow and freezes and closes after a while (Too much stuff appears on screen)

Issue(Most probably)
I didnt use camera or viewport in game first.(This makes game hang after a while on phone but not pc)

later I put camera and viewport in game but then viewport shows too little of game scene on hi res screens (I used 1280x720 for viewport and camera), Now game doesnt hang or freeze but very less of scene is visible

What should be viewport and camera setup for all res devices?(examples welcome)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Images showing what i mean 
https://ibb.co/dGfarR
https://ibb.co/mUivrR

Comment: I don't think `problem of fps fall down is due to any viewport size`, may be it's due to some complex calculation in your game update method

Comment: FPS Falls because much of content in scene starts appearing in the screen  on hi res devices. Low res devices fps is fine and stable at 61 60 . Eg. i created a wall with repeated texture which has 4 repeats on low res but same code produces 8 or more repeats because of hi res (getHeight() thing makes it) so more texture repeats makes interface slower and slower. How can this be tackled?

Comment: viewPort relay on virtual width and height, why your same come generate different valued like 4 to 8, please show your code, so I can understand what's going wrong.

Comment: i use loop to draw textures from 0 to  getHeight() (Texture size 64x64)) so with higher resolution device more tiles form. So viewport shows no effect (i am using FitViewport)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved. The problem was that i was setting camera and viewport resolutions to Gdx.Graphics.getHeight() and width()... which got device height and width.

Thus main cause of problem.

What I needed to do was to set camera and viewport resolutions to virtualResolutions(own desired height x width) like @Abhishek pointed.
After fixing this, both PC and android device show same screens BUT

FPS on android device falls from 45 to 30 and game runs slow.(Although both PC and mobile shows same number of textures) I m using using ExtendViewport

Any suggestions about that?

SOLUTION : USE ONLY ONE SpriteBatch NO MATTER WHAT (I used more than one mistakenly thus lag)

Comment: show your code, you're assigning excessive task to processor ?

Comment: private void drawSprite(SpriteBatch batch){
        for (float y = 0; y < center; y++) {
            Sprite.draw(batch);
            Sprite.setX(xL);
            Sprite.setY(y*64);
    }
This is the basic functionality which is called every few seconds (5)

Comment: PROBABLY SpriteBatch was the issue. I made a static SpriteBatch in a common variables class and now use it everywhere in game. Seems to fix low FPS issue.

Answer (score 1):

[FitViewport](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/FitViewport.html), keeps the aspect ratio by `scaling the world` up to fit the screen, adding black bars (letterboxing) for the remaining space, so always constant number of objects fit to your viewPort.

```
public class GdxTest extends ApplicationAdapter{

    private FitViewport fitViewport;
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private float virtualWidth=640,virtualHeight=400;
    private Texture texture,bg;
    private Sprite Sprite;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        spriteBatch=new SpriteBatch();
        camera=new OrthographicCamera();
        fitViewport=new FitViewport(virtualWidth,virtualHeight,camera);

        texture=new Texture("badlogic.jpg");        // having dimension of 256 X 256
        bg=new Texture("pixel.png");

        Sprite=new Sprite(bg);
        Sprite.setColor(Color.GOLD);
        Sprite.setSize(virtualWidth,virtualHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        spriteBatch.begin();
        Sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.draw(texture,0,0);
        spriteBatch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        fitViewport.update(width, height,true);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        spriteBatch.dispose();
        texture.dispose();
        bg.dispose();
    }
}
```

[image]

I'll recommend [ExtendViewprot](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports#extendviewport) to use, because it keeps the world aspect ratio without black bars by extending the world in one direction.